# How to deal with django-graphene with UUID primary keys in django?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

We use Django and django-graphene to provide GraphQL API. We have UUID primary keys in models. How to properly deal with it?

Comment: Can you provide some more information on how you schema and models are set up? Also what do you mean by "properly deal with it"? Is it not working for you at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that ids serialization (query) is handled pretty straightforwardly by `DjangoObjectType`, I will assume your question relates to mutations.

Also, since good practice is rather oriented towards generating ids on server side, I will also ignore the fact that you mention UUID: I have a feeling this logic should be handled outside of the graphql layer.

The question we therefore seem to be left with is:

> Is there a graphene-django Input field to validate primary keys used as mutation arguments ?

Couldn't find any doc on that, so I ventured with the following:

```py
def PrimaryKey(model: django.db.models.Model):
    """ This contrived way of creating PrimaryKey classes is due to the fact that
        parse_literal is a static method of graphene.Scalar.
    """

    def parse_literal(node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.IntValue):
            pk = node.value
        elif isinstance(node, ast.StringValue):
            pk = int(node.value)
        else:
            raise GraphQLError(f'Unsupported type for PrimaryKey: {type(node)}')
        return model.objects.get(pk=pk)

    return type(
        f'{model.__name__}PrimaryKey',
        (graphene.Scalar,),
        dict(
            parse_literal=parse_literal,
            serialize=lambda x: None,
            parse_value=lambda x: None,
        )
    )
```

Suggestion of usage (not all models shown):

```py
class CreateProject(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        name = graphene.String()
        owner = PrimaryKey(User)  # graphene.List(PrimaryKey(User)) works too

    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, name: str, owner: User):  # owner has been instantiated
        pass  # do business
```